# Get categories query not working in function.php

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I am trying to get the categories of my custom post type in functions.php But it not return any value, when i run this query in any theme file it work fine. Here is my code

```
function get_destinations(){
   $args = array(
    'type'                     => 'accomodation',
    'child_of'                 => 0,
    'parent'                   => '',
    'orderby'                  => 'name',
    'order'                    => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty'               => 1,
    'hierarchical'             => 1,
    'exclude'                  => '',
    'include'                  => '',
    'number'                   => '',
    'taxonomy'                 => 'facilitie',
    'pad_counts'               => false 

); 
 $categories = get_categories($args);$destinations = array();
              foreach ($categories as $cat) { 
                if($cat->cat_name != ''){
                    $destinations[$cat->cat_name] = $cat->cat_name;
                }
          }
return $destinations;
 }
```

I am using [this](https://en.bainternet.info/how-i-add-a-wordpress-metabox/) code to add meta field, now i have to pass the category to select tag which is

```
$my_meta2->addSelect($prefix.'select_field_id',get_destinations(),array('name'=> 'Select Destination'));
```

The original code is like this, they pass the value in array.

```
$my_meta->addSelect($prefix.'select_field_id',array('selectkey1'=>'Select Value1','selectkey2'=>'Select Value2'),array('name'=> 'My select ', 'std'=> array('selectkey2')));
```

But not getting any value, Any idea where i am wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, `get_categories()` won't accept a `post_type` argument. You probably should use taxonomy for that.

You can find more info here:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories

Comment: read the link you post, it have post_type, i use the wordpress query, and as i said it work fine on all pages, except functions.php, which display data on admin side.